# Summing values that are geographically close to each other using Carto?

Tags: postgresql, carto

I have a dataset of Boko Harams rampage in Nigeria uploaded to CartoDB.

I have columns like coordinates, dates, number of victims.

Would it be possible to write a query that would sum the victims within a given radius?

If attack x happens within 10 km from attack y, add the number of victims of attack x to the number of victims of attack y.

Comment: So you basically want to cluster them, right? You can make their distance matrix and then write a greedy algorithm starting from one of them, find all that are less than the desired distance, say _d_, together. That is, each member of the cluster will have at least one other member at most _d_ away. With _d_ sufficiently small, you get what you want in _O(n^2)_.

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you have a row in your table which you want to select as the center of the radius, and the numerical column in which you're storing the victims is called `deaths`:

```
WITH subquery AS (SELECT the_geom FROM tablename WHERE name = 'this is my center')


SELECT sum(tablename.deaths)
FROM tablename, subquery WHERE ST_Intersects(tablename.the_geom, ST_Buffer(subquery.the_geom::geography, 1000000)::geometry)
```

You can add the distance in the ST_Buffer parameter (100000 corresponds to 100Km) or you can use there ST_Distance(point1, point2) to get the distance between two of your existent points. You can get point1 from the A subquery and point2 from a similar one.

Details about ST_Distance can be found here: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html, ST_Intersects: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html, ST_Buffer: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html.